# Which web page element tag is better to use to locate and get value with Webdrive

Tags: c#, css, selenium, xpath, tdd

I am using Selenium for UI tests with **C#**. When I am at the starting step to test the front-end, I have to decide how to "mark" my web elements for future easy test and maintenance. 
So if I have `<input>` or `<div>` or any other element, what is better to use ? `id="element_id"`, `name="element_name"`, `class="class_name"`, or just Xpath ?

Or something else?

Comment: if you have a `id` defined for that element, then use ID (ids are unique to an element and easy for selenium driver to find)

Comment: but what about not to use **id** by csslint and so on

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the way to set a unique element in HTML would be with the `id` tag. Most sites take for granted that the `id` of a tag is unique.

[Schema](https://schema.org/docs/gs.html) is mostly used if you are identifying "items" in your site, which can be usually described this way.

Note that `class` is not unique at all, as it is mostly used for styles and you can use same class on multiple elements and also multiple classes on a single element.

Comment: and what about **name** ? I started thinking that can be a solution. U can name all specific fields u will need in future so that will not affect test success even if page will be re-designed.

Comment: One more thing... If  I use vendor code, how I can bee sure that all my `id`  still unique?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest speaking to your Development team.
From a Developer's perspective if I am going to make changes to the UI to fix a bug or enhance the look and feel , then these changes will affect your Selenium UI Tests. the most least preferred change would be the id="element_id". Developers usually play around with CSS and if you are finding an element Find(By.CssSelector("cssselectors")), if that has changed then your test is going to fail so will Find(By.XPath("//xpath")).

I would say go with Find(By.Id("element_id"));

However, given that everything is changed, then  you will have to change everything in your Test.